# Scikit_learn's PolynomialFeatures with logistic regression resulting in lower scores

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, polynomials

I have a dataset `X` whose shape is (1741, 61). Using logistic regression with cross_validation I was getting around 62-65% for each split (cv =5).

I thought that if I made the data quadratic, the accuracy is supposed to increase. However, I'm getting the opposite effect (I'm getting each split of cross_validation to be in the 40's, percentage-wise) So,I'm presuming I'm doing something wrong when trying to make the data quadratic?

Here is the code I'm using,

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(3)
poly_x =poly.fit_transform(X_scaled)
classifier = LogisticRegression(penalty ='l2', max_iter = 200)

from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(classifier, poly_x, y, cv=5)

array([ 0.46418338,  0.4269341 ,  0.49425287,  0.58908046,  0.60518732])
```

Which makes me suspect, I'm doing something wrong.

I tried transforming the raw data into quadratic, then using `preprocessing.scale`, to scale the data, but it was resulting in an error.

`UserWarning: Numerical issues were encountered when centering the data and might not be solved. Dataset may contain too large values. You may need to prescale your features.
  warnings.warn("Numerical issues were encountered "`

So I didn't bother going this route.

The other thing that's bothering is the speed of the quadratic computations. cross_val_score is taking around a couple of hours to output the score when using polynomial features. Is there any way to speed this up? I have an intel i5-6500 CPU with 16 gigs of ram, Windows 7 OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `MinMaxScaler` instead of the `Scaler`? `Scaler` will output values that are both above and below 0, so you will run into a situation where values with a scaled value of -0.1 and those with a value of 0.1 will have the same squared value, despite not really being similar at all. Intuitively this would seem to be something that would lower the score of a polynomial fit. That being said I haven't tested this, it's just my intuition. Furthermore, be careful with Polynomial fits. I suggest reading [this answer to "Why use regularization in polynomial regression instead of lowering the degree?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226553/why-use-regularisation-in-polynomial-regression-instead-of-lowering-the-degree/226566#226566). It's a great explanation and will likely introduce you to some new techniques. As an aside @MatthewDrury is an excellent teacher and I recommend reading all of his answers and blog posts.

Comment: You bring up an interesting point.  I will test it out, and read the blog you linked.  Thank you.

Comment: First attempt using MinMaxScaler with Poly fit seems to improving the accuracy. I will test it out a few more times, though it will take some time.

Comment: It seems I get a higher accuracy with MinMaxScaler, but I've all of a sudden gotten a higher accuracy with ordinary scaling as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a statement that "the accuracy is supposed to increase" with polynomial features. That is true if the polynomial features brings the model closer to the original data generating process. Polynomial features, especially making every feature interact and polynomial, may move the model further from the data generating process; hence worse results may be appropriate.

By using a 3 degree polynomial in scikit, the X matrix went from (1741, 61) to (1741, 41664), which is significantly more columns than rows.

41k+ columns will take longer to solve. You should be looking at feature selection methods. As Grr says, investigate lowering the polynomial. Try L1, grouped lasso, RFE, Bayesian methods. Try SMEs (subject matter experts who may be able to identify specific features that may be polynomial).  Plot the data to see which features may interact or be best in a polynomial.

I have not looked at it for a while but I recall discussions on hierarchically well-formulated models (can you remove x1 but keep the x1 * x2 interaction). That is probably worth investigating if your model behaves best with an ill-formulated hierarchical model.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't gone into feature selection yet (which I will eventually look into). I was just trying to gauge the benefits of polynomial features, as most lectures I  watched seemed to show a less bias and more variance. Lots of things to test out your post and Grr's post. Thank you.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why the features went from (1741, 61) to 50000's or so.   (61)*(3) +   (61 Choose 2 )  --each feature multiplies with another feature once.